# Sockets and Streams - Mixing StreamReader and BinaryReader

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, stream

I'm working with a socket connection - to make things easier I get the socket's NetworkStream and wrap it up in a StreamReader which makes it easier to work with the largely textual content my socket receives from the server.

However there are times when the server sends binary information, like so:

```
TEXT
MORETEXT
500 BYTES OF BINARY DATA FOLLOWS THIS LINE
{500 bytes of binary data}
```

I'm reading the text content with the StreamReader fine, but because the StreamReader has its own buffer it means the StreamReader grabs the binary data before I can switch to the BinaryReader to read the 500 bytes of binary data.

Is there a way around this? I'd like the ability to read the textual data whilst still being able to read binary data.

Comment: I'm using C# on .NET 3.5, FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should do my research better; it turns out that the BinaryReader class already contains string and character processing methods (though it needs a few, like ReadLine, which can easily be added by subclassing it).

It's strange then, why BinaryReader doesn't subclass TextReader as it is more than capable of.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension of BinaryReader that you can use to perform ReadLine and the usual BinaryReader stuff.

```
public class LineReader : BinaryReader
{
    private Encoding _encoding;
    private Decoder _decoder;

    const int bufferSize = 1024;
    private char[] _LineBuffer = new char[bufferSize];

    public LineReader(Stream stream, int bufferSize, Encoding encoding)
        : base(stream, encoding)
    {
        this._encoding = encoding;
        this._decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();
    }

    public string ReadLine()
    {
        int pos = 0;

        char[] buf = new char[2];

        StringBuilder stringBuffer = null;
        bool lineEndFound = false;

        while(base.Read(buf, 0, 2) > 0)
        {
            if (buf[1] == '\r')
            {
                // grab buf[0]
                this._LineBuffer[pos++] = buf[0];
                // get the '\n'
                char ch = base.ReadChar();
                Debug.Assert(ch == '\n');

                lineEndFound = true;
            }
            else if (buf[0] == '\r')
            {
                lineEndFound = true;
            }                    
            else
            {
                this._LineBuffer[pos] = buf[0];
                this._LineBuffer[pos+1] = buf[1];
                pos += 2;

                if (pos >= bufferSize)
                {
                    stringBuffer = new StringBuilder(bufferSize + 80);
                    stringBuffer.Append(this._LineBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    pos = 0;
                }
            }

            if (lineEndFound)
            {
                if (stringBuffer == null)
                {
                    if (pos > 0)
                        return new string(this._LineBuffer, 0, pos);
                    else
                        return string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (pos > 0)
                        stringBuffer.Append(this._LineBuffer, 0, pos);
                    return stringBuffer.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        if (stringBuffer != null)
        {
            if (pos > 0)
                stringBuffer.Append(this._LineBuffer, 0, pos);
            return stringBuffer.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            if (pos > 0)
                return new string(this._LineBuffer, 0, pos);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```